# How to find the sum of elements in the power of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

> Given a matrix $A$, what is the most effective method by which one can obtain the sum of elements of $A^n$?

I was thinking of some property related to matrices that would solve this problem without carrying out $n$ multiplications to find $A^n$.

Comment: To just find $A^n$ (not even considering the sum part of the question), the general method is to diagonalize (if possible)/convert to Jordan form, then calculate $A^n = UD^nU^\dagger$, where $D$ is either diagonal or in Jordan canonical form.  In either case, $D^n$ is simple to compute in this case.

It can be more effective to employ other methods if $A$ is a specific class of matrix already (I believe there are more efficient methods for Toeplitz matrices, but don't entirely know), but that strategy is generally pretty good.

Comment: Additionally, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem if $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, then $A^m$ can always be expressed as a linear combination of $\lbrace I, A,\dots, A^{n-1}\rbrace$.  So, if computing these "basis matrices" isn't too time consuming (so, if $n$ is small enough), this can be employed.  As an example, if $A$ is $4\times 4$ with characteristic polynomial $t^4+a_3t^3+a_2t^2+a_1t^1+a_0$, then we have that $A^4 = -a_3A^3-a_2A^2-a_1A-a_0I$, and $A^{100}=(A^{4})^{25}=(-a_3A^3-a_2A^2-a_1A-a_0I)^{25}$.  We expand, then substitute out $A^4$ where possible to find something in terms of the basis

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=[1,\cdots,1]^T\in \mathbb{R}^p,A,B\in M_{p,p}$. We look for $u^TA^nu$. To calculate $u^TB$ (resp $BA$) needs $2p^2$ (resp. $2p^3$) operations $+,\times$.

You can consider the following two methods:

1. Calculate $u_1=u^TA,u_2=u_1A,\cdots$, $output=u_nu$. The cost is $\sim 2np^2$ operations.
2. Calculate $A^n,u^TA^nu$; using the binary decomposition of $n$, the cost of the calculation of $A^n$ is $\leq 2\log(n)$ matrix multiplications, that is $4p^3\log(n)$ operations.

It remains to compare $n$ and $p\log(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $u=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 &1 &. &.&.& 1\end{bmatrix}^T$.

For a fixed $n\in \Bbb N$ compute $A^nu=A^{n-1}(Au)$

You will get all the row sums.Now just add all the row sums.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(m,k)$ be the function that gives the sum of all entries of the matrix $m$ to the $k$-th power, $k\geq 0$

This is not a proof but here is a formula that maybe of interest

$$g(m,k)=\text{tr}(m)g(m,k-1)-\det (m)g(m,k-2)$$

where $tr$ is the trace and $det$ is the determinant

Comment: @Lozenges....if this property works...it would greatly simplify my problem...thanks!

Comment: @Lozenges that formula is only valid for $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: @themaker yes, you are right